# Angular momentum about centre of mass is not always equal to $I_\text{com}\omega$, Right?

Tags: angular-momentum, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

Angular momentum about a point on the rotational axis is equal to sum of angular momentum perpendicular to rotational axis and angular momentum parallel to rotational axis. The perpendicular component vanishes if the body is symmetrical about the axis of rotation. So when we say $I_\text{com}\omega$ is angular momentum about COM isn't it neglecting the cases where bodies are not symmetrical? The problem came when we have angular momentum about some point (say $O$) for a rolling body: the derivation leads to $L_O = I_\text{cm}\omega + M(r\times V_\text{cm})$. So some sources are saying $I_\text{cm}\omega$ is angular momentum about COM. Isn't it wrong to call it angular momentum about COM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This discussion is for a rigid body.

For planar motion, using the center of mass (CM) as the origin and the $\hat z$ axis as the fixed axis of rotation $J_z = I_z \omega$, but if the axis of rotation is not a principal axis $J_x$ and $J_y$ are not zero since the products of inertia are not zero.  $\vec J$ is the angular momentum about the CM, $I_z$ is the moment of inertia about the axis, and $\vec \omega$ is the angular velocity about the axis of rotation.

For general rotation about a point $\vec J = \tilde I \cdot \vec\omega$  where $\tilde I$ is the inertia tensor.

See Goldstein, Classical Mechanics or Symon, Mechanics.

Comment: So can you give the conclusion to what I asked..as of now I only require a conclusion and may be why I am right or wrong...I have not studied the concepts on the level you are talking about(tensors etc)..So could you just say whether I am right or wrong and why so ? Thank you.

Comment: The total angular momentum about the CM is not in general $I_{CM} \omega$ so you are correct.

Comment: Thanks manh that helps .

Comment: They are talking about the component of angular momentum along a fixed axis of rotation but that is not the total angular momentum if the axis is not a principal axis.

Comment: I saw your comment only after posting...but still thanx for coming up again... principal axis concept I will only learn in higher classes..so this will do thank you

Comment: Yes, principal axes are trival for a symmetric body, but not for a non-symmetric body; this is where the inertia tensor comes into use (a generalizatoin of the moment of inertia).  You will learn about this later :)